# MongoDB connection issue in GitLab pipeline Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker, rspec, gitlab

I'm trying to run some automated tests for a Ruby on Rails application in a GitLab pipeline using a MongoDB database.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
stages:
- build
- test
- deploy
- review
- dast
- staging
- canary
- production
- incremental rollout 10%
- incremental rollout 25%
- incremental rollout 50%
- incremental rollout 100%
- performance
- cleanup
sast:
  stage: test
include:
- template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  TEST_MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://mongo-test:27017/?directConnection=true"

run tests:
  stage: test
  image: ruby:3.2.2
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
  services:
    - name: mongo:5
      alias: mongo-test
  script:
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rspec
  coverage: /\(\d+.\d+\%\) covered/
```

My mongoid.yml file looks for the env variable `TEST_MONGO_DB_URI`

```
test:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['TEST_MONGODB_URI'] %>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable:
No primary_preferred server is available in cluster: #<Cluster topology=Single[mongo-test:27017] servers=[#<Server address=mongo-test:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015
```

I am logging out the attempted connection URI as the tests initiate, and it is the same as the env variable I am setting in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Here's what I've tried:

- removing the directConnection=true option
- adding `command: ['mongod']` to the service.
- adding a `docker:dind` service to the config.
- specifying the mongodb service outside of the run_tests stage.

These all resulted in the same error.

I assume this is an issue with the container running mongodb being unable to accept requests from the container running the gitlab runner. I'm pretty unfamiliar with gitlab, but from what I understand each service runs in the same container as the script being ran in each step, so connectivity should be as simple as mongodb://mongo-test:27017.